# New tag for multiple voices issue helpful?

Tags: discussion, tags

This [question](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/99357/2600) is only the latest of a re-curring kind of question: too many notes in a bar due to multiple voices in one system. It is quite difficult to find one of the numerous duplicates due to lack of a convincing tag.

None of the *poly** tags seems appropriate, neither *multi** (multitrack would somehow fit, but is unlikely to be considered by somebody asking) and the **voice** tags all imply singing.

This leaves *notation* and *time-signature* (or even an instrument-specific like *piano*), which have already a quite broad scope limiting their usefulness for searches.

Answer (score 8):

So there are two different questions here: what to do about the mass amount of duplicates of the questions that have confusions about multiple voices and should there be a tag for questions that are about multiple voices.

The first question is easy, we can use the meta to track some of these question and make a list here about the historically canonical questions so the duplicates can be linked easily. These questions are easily the most common question that seems to come up a lot. One reason why I think this question is asked a lot is that the posters don't know about the concept of multiple voices so I don't think the tag alone will help new users find these questions.

Here is a quick list feel free to add to it:

- [Too many notes in this measure](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/53041/too-many-notes-in-this-measure)
- [Rest above a note in a piano piece](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/15929/rest-above-a-note-in-a-piano-piece)
- [Some measures have extra whole notes in them. What do they mean?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/65701/some-measures-have-extra-whole-notes-in-them-what-do-they-mean)
- [How should i play this 4/4 measure with 4 quarter notes and 1 whole note in it](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/90514/how-should-i-play-this-4-4-measure-with-4-quarter-notes-and-1-whole-note-in-it)
- [Please help me with how to do the left hand](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/95341/please-help-me-with-how-to-do-the-left-hand)
- [How to play a note while the same note is being held?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/23158/how-to-play-a-note-while-the-same-note-is-being-held)
- [Notation that means “same as previous four?”](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/101026/notation-that-means-same-as-previous-four)
- [Music Notation (in Musescore) - Ties or Separate Voices?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/99297/music-notation-in-musescore-ties-or-separate-voices)
- [What is this double-note and how do you play it?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/45167/what-is-this-double-note-and-how-do-you-play-it)
- [Why does this note have a stem pointing up and another pointing down?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/33948/why-does-this-note-have-a-stem-pointing-up-and-another-pointing-down)
- [How do I read the music when there are more beats in bar than the time signature specifies](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/103544/how-do-i-read-the-music-when-there-are-more-beats-in-bar-than-the-time-signature)

---

For the second question we can always add new tags,but we should do so when they are needed. The only thing holding me back from just saying yes is I don't know how much application this tag has outside of these questions. If it does, making the tag makes sense. If it does not then the duplicates linked should be enough. I found [one question that isn't a direct duplicate that could use this tag](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/95699/how-to-interpret-this-two-voice-timing-it-looks-like-there-are-only-three-notes) so there seems to be some use of it outside these questions.

If we do decide we want a tag, I suggest using the tag [multiple-vocies](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-vocies) and explain in the except the tag is for questions pertain to multiple voices on a staff and not to use if it's just about vocal music to keep the tag clean.

---

EDIT: Some more for the proposed duplicates list.

- [Guitar tab reading](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/36417/guitar-tab-reading)
- [How do i play a quaver and semi quaver together?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/88336/how-do-i-play-a-quaver-and-semi-quaver-together)